# Body of email macro issue

Tags: excel, vba

The code below helps in selecting a range of cells as the body of the email and sending it but when I select a range, not the complete range of cells gets sent as an email, only part of the range is sent as an email.

How do I perfectly select a range of cells as the body of an email to send?

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim last_row As Integer

    last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))


    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:L40").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With


    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 2 To last_row
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        .cc = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
    If sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
        .attachments.Add sh.Range("C" & i).Value
    End If

    If sh.Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
        .attachments.Add sh.Range("C" & i).Value
    End If

        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send

    End With
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Separate function `"RangetoHTML(rng As Range)"` has been used.

Comment: `Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` What is `Selection` ? That might be the source of your issue try to avoid it ! Maybe If you tell me what is the selection (Which cells/range) I can give you some help !

Comment: Does the same portion of your selection always show up?  Please provide more information about what is happening, as well as more information around the desired outcome.

Comment: Suggest posting the RangetoHTML as part of your code block. It looks like a function i've seen before and if any edits have been made to that function it will affect the output.